# manage field population in edit form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4 and I have this form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

use App\Entity\TypeParking;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TypeParkingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('tempsmax')
            ->add('jourdebut')
            ->add('jourfin')


            ->add('Exception_Name', TextType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[name]'])
            ->add('Starting_date', DateType::class, [
                'property_path' => 'exception[datedebut]',
            ])
            ->add('Ending_date', DateType::class, [
                'property_path' => 'exception[datefin]',
            ])
            ->add('Starting_time', TimeType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heuredebut]'])
            ->add('Ending_time', TimeType::class, ['property_path' => 'exception[heurefin]'])


        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TypeParking::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I create a new form I usually take the values of Exception_Name,Starting_date,Ending_date,Starting_time and Ending_time manually and put them into a single json array in a single database field. 
However when I go to edit the form, the data inside the json doesn't get divided to populate each of the fields.

let's say that I have this json array: {"Exceptions": {"name": "6fdfs", "StartDate": "2015-03-03", "StartHour": "00:00:00", "EndingDate": "2015-03-03", "EndingHour": "00:00:00"}}
I'm gonna take the name value and use it to populate the Exception_Name field, etc...

TL;DR: How can I control how I want to pre-populate each field of the edit form

**Edit:**
this is my datamapper

```
<?php
// src/Form/DataMapper/ColorMapper.php
namespace App\Form\DataMapper;

use App\Painting\Color;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataMapperInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

final class TypeParkingMapper implements DataMapperInterface
{
    /**
     * @param TypeParking|null $data
     */
    public function mapDataToForms($data, $forms)
    {
        // there is no data yet, so nothing to prepopulate
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var FormInterface[] $forms */
        $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
       // initialize form field values
       $Excep=$data->getException();
       $forms['Exception_Name']->setData($Excep['Exceptions']['name']);
       $forms['Starting_date']->setData($Excep['Exceptions']['StartDate']);
       $forms['Ending_date']->setData($Excep['Exceptions']['EndingDate']);
       $forms['Starting_time']->setData($Excep['Exceptions']['StartHour']);
       $forms['Ending_time']->setData($Excep['Exceptions']['EndingHoure']);



    }

    public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
    {
        /** @var FormInterface[] $forms */
        $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);

        // as data is passed by reference, overriding it will change it in
        // the form object as well
        // beware of type inconsistency, see caution below
        $data = new TypeParking(
            $forms['Exception_Name']->getData()

        );
    }
}
```

So it works fine when I edit an object (since getException() returns the json array from my database), but when I create a new object it throws an error since there's no data to get.
So is there any way I can turn the mapper off when I create a new form and only activate it when editing a form ?

the error is : "Notice: Undefined index: Exceptions"

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [DataMapper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html) to fully control how your data is mapped to your form.

Comment: that only works if you're using Sonata bundle, I'm using plain symfony 4.

Comment: @Hyperion no, DataMappers are mainly from Symfony. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html

Comment: I figured how to use it (kinda), it works fine when editing an existing object, but whenever I want to create a new one I get an error because it couldn't find any object, is there any way to disable it when creating new forms ?

Comment: Could you write what error are you getting? Also - I believe that in the link @Jakumi gave the first 3 lines in `mapDataToForms` should handle your case.

Comment: Can you also paste the `TypeParking` entity? Can there be more than one exception in the JSON (as the plural key `Exceptions` kinda suggests)? If so, should the form display all of them? Should there be a possibility to add (and/or remove) another exception on that form?